# Mozilla Thunderbird Lightning sending invite to "unknown@somewhere.com

Tags: mozilla, lightning

Using Mozilla Thunderbird 31.4.0 on Ubuntu Linux, along with Lighning Calendar.  For some reason, every time I send a meeting invite, it adds a invitee with the email address 
unknown@somewhere.com.

I have no idea where this is coming from but would like to stop it.

Comment: Can you add more information, for example what calendar type the invitation is on, what addons you use, and if there are any debug logs of relevance when calendar.debug.log and calendar.debug.log.verbose are on in the config editor? Also, check if you have any default CC or BCC entries for the mail identities being used.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this behaviour is caused by leaving the cursor at the end of the line containing the address of the last invitee, when adding people to the invitee list.  If I go to the next line, and just leave a blank invitee, it seems that it doesn't send the invite to this phantom person.

Hope that help, perhaps a bug that could be fixed?

Thanks

J

Comment: For bug reports, please visit bugzilla.mozilla.org. It could be an autocomplete bug in an older version. If you'd like a stackoverflow answer, please provide more details.